# How to create rolling window variables without skipping months when using a multiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Currently I have a df with a location_key & year_month multiIndex. I want to create a sum using a rolling window for 3 months.

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['LOCATION_KEY','YEAR_MONTH'])['SALES'].count()).sort_index()).groupby(level=(0)).apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=3).sum())
```

The window is working properly the issue is that in months where there were no sales instead of counting an empty month instead it counts the another month.

e.g. in the data below, 2016-03 Sales is the sum of 2016-03, 2016-01, 2015-12 as opposed to what I would like: 2016-03, 2016-02, 2016-01.

`LOCATION_KE YEAR_MONTH SALES
A           2015-10 NaN
            2015-11 NaN
            2015-12 200
            2016-01 220
            2016-03 180
B           2015-04 NaN
            2015-05 NaN
            2015-06 119
            2015-07 120`

Comment: Try reindexing on YEAR_MONTH monthly with a fill of 0.

Comment: Something like: df.reindex(pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods=24, freq='M'), fill_value=0)

Comment: @Kyle how do I do this maintaining the location key. So I have 24 rows for every location key.

Comment: What is your expected output from this data?

Comment: @ScottBoston The goal is a rolling window count that counts 0 if the month is not included in the list as opposed to counting an extra month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have to get your index set up how you want so the rolling window has zeros to process.

```
df
  LOCATION_KE YEAR_MONTH  SALES
0           A 2015-10-01    NaN
1           A 2015-11-01    NaN
2           A 2015-12-01  200.0
3           A 2016-01-01  220.0
4           A 2016-03-01  180.0
5           B 2015-04-01    NaN
6           B 2015-05-01    NaN
7           B 2015-06-01  119.0
8           B 2015-07-01  120.0

df['SALES'] = df['SALES'].fillna(0)

df.index = [df["LOCATION_KE"], df["YEAR_MONTH"]]

df
                       LOCATION_KE YEAR_MONTH  SALES
LOCATION_KE YEAR_MONTH
A           2015-10-01           A 2015-10-01    0.0
            2015-11-01           A 2015-11-01    0.0
            2015-12-01           A 2015-12-01  200.0
            2016-01-01           A 2016-01-01  220.0
            2016-03-01           A 2016-03-01  180.0
B           2015-04-01           B 2015-04-01    0.0
            2015-05-01           B 2015-05-01    0.0
            2015-06-01           B 2015-06-01  119.0
            2015-07-01           B 2015-07-01  120.0


df = df.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['LOCATION_KE'], 
                                            pd.date_range("20150101", periods=24, freq='MS')],
                                           names=['location', 'month']))



df['SALES'].fillna(0).reset_index(level=0).groupby('location').rolling(3).sum().fillna(0)
                    location  SALES
location month
A        2015-01-01        A    0.0
         2015-02-01        A    0.0
         2015-03-01        A    0.0
         2015-04-01        A    0.0
         2015-05-01        A    0.0
         2015-06-01        A    0.0
         2015-07-01        A    0.0
         2015-08-01        A    0.0
         2015-09-01        A    0.0
         2015-10-01        A    0.0
         2015-11-01        A    0.0
         2015-12-01        A  200.0
         2016-01-01        A  420.0
         2016-02-01        A  420.0
         2016-03-01        A  400.0
         2016-04-01        A  180.0
         2016-05-01        A  180.0
         2016-06-01        A    0.0
         2016-07-01        A    0.0
         2016-08-01        A    0.0
         2016-09-01        A    0.0
         2016-10-01        A    0.0
         2016-11-01        A    0.0
         2016-12-01        A    0.0
         2015-01-01        A    0.0
         2015-02-01        A    0.0
         2015-03-01        A    0.0
         2015-04-01        A    0.0
         2015-05-01        A    0.0
         2015-06-01        A    0.0
...                      ...    ...
B        2016-07-01        B    0.0
         2016-08-01        B    0.0
         2016-09-01        B    0.0
         2016-10-01        B    0.0
         2016-11-01        B    0.0
         2016-12-01        B    0.0
         2015-01-01        B    0.0
         2015-02-01        B    0.0
         2015-03-01        B    0.0
         2015-04-01        B    0.0
         2015-05-01        B    0.0
         2015-06-01        B  119.0
         2015-07-01        B  239.0
         2015-08-01        B  239.0
         2015-09-01        B  120.0
         2015-10-01        B    0.0
         2015-11-01        B    0.0
         2015-12-01        B    0.0
         2016-01-01        B    0.0
         2016-02-01        B    0.0
         2016-03-01        B    0.0
         2016-04-01        B    0.0
         2016-05-01        B    0.0
         2016-06-01        B    0.0
         2016-07-01        B    0.0
         2016-08-01        B    0.0
         2016-09-01        B    0.0
         2016-10-01        B    0.0
         2016-11-01        B    0.0
         2016-12-01        B    0.0
```

I think if you have a up to date pandas you can leave out the reset_index.

Comment: everything I was trying was relating to pd.grouper or resample. MultiIndex was not on my radar. Thanks!